# load contact query in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I'm trying to show contact data in a listview. I think all it's ok but when I execute the app I have the follow error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView`.
The code is this:

```
public class BuscaContactos extends Activity {
    ListView listContactos;
    String opcion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_busca_contactos);
        listContactos=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listContactos);
        ArrayList<String> listagente = consultaAgenda();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BuscaContactos.this, R.layout.activity_busca_contactos,listagente);
        listContactos.setAdapter(adapter);
        listContactos.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<String> consultaAgenda() {
        ArrayList<String> datos = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String ContactID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String nombre = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            datos.add(ContactID);
            datos.add(nombre);
        }
        c.close();
        return datos;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your are trying to show contact number in list view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.layout.activity_busca_contactos` should contain a `TextView` nothing else.

If you want to use other `View` then you need to create a `CustomAdapter`

Comment: But I don't use any TextView for anything

Comment: Then what is in the layout?

Comment: The layout has only the ListView

Comment: You have to pass the layout that you want to use for inflating in the rows. Try replacing `R.layout.activity_busca_contactos` with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Comment: Are you sure your `ArrayList` is not empty?

Comment: I forget to add `,listagente` after the inflate. Thank you